# run django with supervisor and gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

I am running django app through gunicorn with supervisor. although supervisor starts the app and app is running fine through supervisor but is says
`test                             FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`
due to this i can not control/stop my app through supervisor. i have checked logs but the log files are empty.
CONFIG FILE

```
[program:test]
directory=/home/djangouser/mysite
command=/home/djangouser/env/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn  mysite.wsgi --config /home/djangouser/conf/gunicorn.py
autostart=true 
autorestart=true 
stderr_logfile=/home/djangouser/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log 
stdout_logfile=/home/djangouser/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
user=root
```

I repeat after supervisorctl update app is running but giving error.

Comment: Show us the contents of /home/djangouser/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log and /home/djangouser/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log

Comment: @EneP As i mentioned log files are empty no logs there